# Mercurial alias doesn't output to editor

Tags: vim, mercurial, alias

I often end up needing to see the difference between my current commit + changes and the previous one. I do this by `hg diff --rev .^`

Since I do this a lot, I made an alias for it, which I called `pdiff`. Howver, when I run this, if the differences takes more space than the terminal, I can't navigate using vim bindings, it puts all the output in terminal.

Is there a way to get it to act the same as typing out the full command?

Comment: Can't you pipe it to a pager? Something like `$ hg diff --rev .^ | less`.

Comment: Trying to pipe to `less` in my `~/.hgrc` doesn't work, it's trying to treat `|` and `less` as file names.

Comment: It's time to write a proper shell script, don't you think?

Comment: Writing a shell script when I could just type `hg diff --rev .^` to get my desired behavior seems excessive. I'm more curious about why it acts differently when it's put under an alias in `~/.hgrc`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have (for Mercurial 3, I suppose for earlier versions  - too) wrong syntax for revset "N-th parent of".</strike> From `hg help revsets`

> ```
> "x^n"
>  The nth parent of x, n == 0, 1, or 2.
> ```

If you have to use OS-level features, you have to read about [shell aliases](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias)

> An alias can start with an exclamation point (!) to make it a shell alias. A shell alias is executed with the shell and will let you run arbitrary commands.

and your `pdiff` will be something like

`pdiff = !$HG diff -r .^$1 | less`

and used as `pdiff (0|1|2)` for getting changes from second|first parent of working dir or working dir directly

Comment: "x^" -> Equivalent to "x^1", the first parent of each changeset in x. http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets

Comment: @Vince - mea culpa, fixed